# Hibernate annotations: One to one

Tags: hibernate, annotations

I have two different tables, Person table and Employee table. I need a one-to-one mapping between these two. Employee table's emp_id references Person table's person_id. I need some help in writing the mapping using annotations

Comment: The Hibernate documentation, the JPA specification, the Java EE api documentation, and Google are all freely available. That should be sufficient to at least try something, and come back here with a concrete question and the code you tried if you're stuck.

Comment: Hey Hi....I did try it out its just that i could get it working using the mapping xmls but with annotations i keep getting null pointer exception....

Comment: it would be of great help if you could let me know what should be corrected in the following code:

Comment: Then your question should be "why am I getting a NullPointerException when executing the following code?". And it should include the relevant code and the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: persons.java

@OneToOne(mappedBy="persons1", cascade=CascadeType.ALL) public Employee getemployee() {}

EMPLOYEE.JAVA

@oneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")

Comment: Edit your question. Don't post comments.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://morejava4u.blogspot.com/2013/09/one-to-one-relationship-in-hibernate.html) is the example for One to one mapping using annotation.